# Apache Camel consumersCount - how does it work?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

Per documentation, "The # of consumers that connect to kafka server. Each consumer is run on a separate thread, that retrieves and process the incoming data".

So if I have 5 kafka partitions, 1 consumer group with 5 servers running same Camel project setup for this same consumer group. I understand that each consumer will be assigned to 1 kafka partition so I will have a max of 5 consumers.

```
server 1, consumer 1 assigned to --> partition 0
server 2, consumer 2 assigned to --> partition 1
server 3, consumer 3 assigned to --> partition 2
server 4, consumer 4 assigned to --> partition 3
server 5, consumer 5 assigned to --> partition 4
```

Now if I set consumersCount = 3 for the Camel project, does that mean Consumer 1 from server 1 will have 3 threads of consumer reading from partition 0 in concurrent? So on for the other 4 servers... so I will have a total of 15 consumers this way?

I'm running this using Spring Boot.

Thanks in advance!
Andrew.

Just a question stated above.

Comment: Which version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Hi, we are using 3.2.0

Comment: That's a really old version that is no longer supported. Could you please also add your code especially your camel route

Comment: Hi, it is like this: from(kafka:topicName?brokers=servername&consumersCount=5&...), see ConsumersCount property. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `consumersCount` is set to 5 and you have 5 servers running the same Camel Route with the same Kafka settings and the same `group.id`. Kafka will see a consumer group composed of 25 members that consume one topic of 5 partitions so 20 members won't have any partitions assigned.

So in your case, depending on your needs/requirements, either you just get rid of the parameter `consumersCount` to have only 5 consumers or you change the number of partitions of your topic to 25 on your topic.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas! So the jist of this is the # of consumers in a same consumer group can NEVER exceed the total # of Kafka partitions as I already knew. I was asking as I was thinking may be Camel does something extra in this aspect with this consumerCount. Thanks!

Comment: No Camel doesn't do anything special